# How to add a tooltip(or a title tag) to tapestry grid rows?

Tags: tapestry

How to add a tooltip(or a title tag) to tapestry grid rows? I want to show row sensitive information in the tool tip. I could do it in `t:loop` but I need to use `t:grid`. I do not need an additional column in the grid.

I am using tapestry version 5.0.18.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written a GridDecorator mixin which applies decorators to rows and cells after a grid component has rendered. The decorators have a reference to the DOM element and the bean that was used to draw the grid row. So you can decorate the DOM however you like (for example adding a context menu to every row that is specific to the row).

Demo/Code here:

- http://t5stitch-lazan.rhcloud.com/griddecoratordemo

Answer (score 1):

I have put the question also on the tapestry user group [here](http://tapestry.1045711.n5.nabble.com/Adding-a-tooltip-or-a-title-tag-to-tapestry-grid-rows-td4895543.html). As I understand from the answers there is no direct way to do this.

But I had some success in the below method.

Tapestry grids gets transformed in to table in the rendered html page. Using java script we can attach a title tag on to each row.

```
jQuery('td.rowtitle').attr('width', '12%').attr('title', '${message:yourMessage}');
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the question. I learned what I was looking for from Henning's answer, but that syntax is deprecated in Tapestry 5.3 and won't work (unless, perhaps, I reconfigure Tapestry to ignore deprecations). Here is the "modern" version of Henning's example

```
<t:grid ...>
    <p:lastNameHeader>
        <!-- your content -->
    </p:lastNameHeader>
<t:grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the default table headers and cells and fill them with anything you like:

```
<table t:type="Grid" ...>
    <t:parameter name="lastNameHeader">
        <!-- Your content -->
    </t:parameter>
</table>
```

The name of the parameters is "${nameOfRow}Header" for the header and "${nameOfRow}Cell" for the cells.

Also take a look at the [Grid component reference](http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry5.0/tapestry-core/ref/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/Grid.html).